# How an object is treated when it calls a method of its superclass?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

I am trying foolish things to make the concept clear about the swings (which component i can add to which) and inheritance.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
JFrame g = new JFrame();
f.add(g); // i know that its silly.
```

it compiles fin because `JFrame` is a `container` and `add` method is defined in it. Its declaration is

```
Component add ( Component comp);
```

and if i do the funny stuff as above i get the exception saying

> adding a window to a container.

What i have analysed from this is when we call a method that is defined in the above class in the inheritance tree that object is treated as an object of that above class in inheritance tree.As here when we do

```
f.add(g);
```

`f` is treated as container because `add()` is not defined in `JFrame` but is defined in its parent (or parent to parent more specifically) that is `Container`.While `g` is treated as Component because `JFrame` is a `Component` also.

This seems a true or false question but please explain me technically, that what i believe is right or not?

But why exception is saying

> adding a window to a container.

and why not

> adding a container to a component.

as `g` is passed to `add()` as a `component`?

My third question is that what is the need of recursive inheritance between `Component` and `Container`?

**EDIT** why the exception is saying so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JFrame  extends Frame extends Window extends Container extends Component`

So indirectly `JFrame` is a `Component` and `jframe.add(jframe2)` is *legal* and as `JFrame` is child of `Window` message is saying that `adding a window to a container.` is illegal.

As it's checked in class `Container` as follow,

```
 /**
 * Checks that the component is not a Window instance.
 */
 private void checkNotAWindow(Component comp){
    if (comp instanceof Window) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("adding a window to a container");
     }
 }
```

Comment: oh! check is made for instanceof Window so that we cannot add Frame JFrame or even Dialog to a  Container ? am i right?

Answer (score 5):

The hierarchy of JFrame is like this,

```
java.awt.Component
 java.awt.Container
  java.awt.Window
   java.awt.Frame
    javax.swing.JFrame
```

A `JFrame` is a `Component`, `Container` and a `Window` as well.

So, why is the exception saying **adding a window to a container** and not **container to a container**,

that's because you can add a `Container` to a `Container`. Example, `JPanel` to a `JFrame`.

You only cannot add a `Window` to a `Container`. Because `Window`s are for top level components and not meant to be inside another component.

And for your **third question:**

> what is the need of recursive inheritance between Component and Container?

There's no need for that. And it's not so too. A `Container` is a `Component`. But a `Component` need not always be a `Container`. It's just multilevel inheritance you are seeing here for JFrame. Not recursive.